# C++ Ambiguous access - virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ambiguous, virtual-inheritance, compiler-bug

I tried to call the default constructor of the virtual base class `X` from its most-derived class `V`. I do not know why calling `X`'s constructor from `V` is considered an ambiguous access. Can anyone help?

The code is below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    X() { cout << "X"; }
};

class Y : virtual public X {
public:
    Y() { cout << "Y"; }
};

class Z : public X {
public:
    Z() { cout << "Z"; }
};

class V : public Y, public Z {
public:
    V() : X() {}
};

int main() {
    V v;
}
```

Comment: Compiles here: https://ideone.com/Eon4tU. What is your compiler?

Comment: Which compiler? gcc 9.2.1 has no issues with this. Your compiler is obviously getting confused due to multiple inheritance of `X`.

Comment: also on my clang compiler it doesn't create any problem

Comment: MSVC happily gives an error.

Comment: I ran it in Viusal Studio

Comment: Indeed, compare the three compilers on the code: https://godbolt.org/z/-FcXEC . This is an MSVC bug.

Comment: Reopened. The other question does not explain why this access is ambiguous (since this one is not actually ambiguous; MSVC is just incorrect).

Comment: it is typical dreaded  diamond problem with multiple inheritance.  this would help you to understand more
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-where

Comment: @pmp How is this "dreaded"? What's the big problem?

Comment: @curiousguy there exist two path for accessing `x`,  through `vptr` of  `Y` and via `Z` and hence compiler is unable to resolve path for constructor call of `X`

Comment: @pmp What does the vptr has to do with name or function lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously adding some member function in the common base would allow to have an ambiguous call:

```
class X {
public:
    X() { cout << "X"; }
    void f();
};
```

Then `this->f()` in `V` is ambiguous (obviously: which `V::X::f`?).

My guess is that the name of base classes was looked up as if it was "the name of a constructor member in a base class, looked up as a non static member" by the compiler, and thus found to be ambiguous as there are two `V::X()` pseudo-"inherited" constructor.

There is exactly one direct or virtual base `X` of `V` so the init-list doesn't seem ambiguous.

Comment: If your theory were correct then it should accept `struct W : Z { W(): X() {} };` but it does not

Comment: @M.M Just because `X` can be found by name lookup, and is unambiguous, does not imply that it will be considered valid in that context. Do you get an ambiguous name lookup here? If not, it doesn't invalidate the theory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since `Z` does not not inherit from `X` with `virtual`, you don't have virtual inheritance here -- you have non-virtual inheritance, so there are mulitple `X` subobjects which you can't access directly from the top level, as it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Class inheritance is roughly considered as creating member object,
Example,

```
class A { }
class B : public A {}
```

Can be put as

```
class A { }
class B { public: A obj;}
```

Below I tried to depict the scenario with which you can inherit in a diamond structure,
case1 : Here two instance of `X` is present in `V` (i.e `V::Y::X` and `V::Z::X` )

```
           X
         /   \
        /     \
public /       \ public
      Y         Z
       \       /
        \     /
         \   /
           V
```

case2: `V` will have only one instance of `X` i.e single instance of memory is allocated (i.e `V::Y::X` and `V::Z::X` will point to same instance of `X`) and hence explicit constructor of 'X' needs to be called from `V` unless there exists a `default` constructor

```
                   X
                 /   \
                /     \
virtual public /       \ virtual public
              Y         Z
               \       /
                \     /
                 \   /
                   V
```

Case3: Same as problem defined by you, two paths for inheritance exists and base class accepts default constructor. You can skip the explicit call of base class constructor or call with `X::X()`,`Z::X()` or `Y::x()` to instantiate instance of `Y::X`

```
                   X
                 /   \
                /     \
virtual public /       \ public
              Y         Z
               \       /
                \     /
                 \   /
                   V
```

Here is the case without default constructor,

```
class x { public: x(int d) { data = d; }    int data; };

class y : virtual public x { public: y():x(10) {} };

class z : public x { public:z():x(20){  } };

class v : public y, public z { public: v():z::x(200) {} };

int main() {        
    v obj;
    std::cout << obj.y::data << " ";
    std::cout << obj.z::data << std::endl;
}
```

Output: `200 10`

Answer (score -1):

Some compilers work iff **all children** have inherited the base (here `X`) using `virtual` keyword in the situation like yours.

```
class Z : virtual public X {
//        ^^^^^^^ try this
```

The reason for that is nicely explained in the accepted answer of the following post: [Diamond problem with only 1 virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534945/diamond-problem-with-only-1-virtual-inheritance)

Comment: Yes, but that has a different meaning, and the original code is allowed per the Standard.

Comment: I am not sure. You may see the linked duplicate @aschepler. BTW, do you have any reference which states that if only one derived class inherits the base virtually then it's OK as per standard?

Comment: @aschepler, that link suggests the other way around. It interprets from the graph that, a class at bottom of the diamond would have only 1 copy of the top class of the diamond, only if all the intermediate classes inherit virtually. The duplicate Qn confirms this part. Hence the compiler error seems reasonable in this case.

Comment: Yes, if a derived class inherits a base class both virtually and non-virtually, then there are multiple base class subobjects. But that's a legal thing to do. It can cause ambiguous name lookup problems, but there are also valid ways to use this pattern. And the original code here is fine because the subobject initializers in a constructor may only name a virtual base class or direct base class, not an indirect non-virtual base like the `Z`-in-`X`-in-`V`, so that particular line is not ambiguous.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question